# Ubuntu Server 10.04: Certain services (mysql, nsd3, lighttp etc) won't start at boot

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I'm running Ubuntu Server 10.04. I've installed mysql, nsd3, lighttpd, but nothing but sshd will start when I reboot. I can start them manually. What do I do to make these start at boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to Ubuntu bugs #554172 or #497299.

Try making sure your loopback interface is defined properly in /etc/network/interfaces

EDIT: Assuming that the services are actually set to start at boot, which usually happens during package installation.

Comment: The loopback does appear to be correctly configured: 

# Auto generated lo interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


The startup scripts are in the correct directory, but not all of them seem to run correctly, if I invoke them manually. For example: 

./S20anacron status
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service S20anacron status

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the status(8) utility, e.g. status S20anacron
status: Unknown job: S20anacron

I don't know what this means.

Comment: The command you're looking for is "status anacron" or "service start anacron".

Judging from http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html you might want to try editing /etc/init/<service name>.conf

Comment: That did it for mysql - just a quick change to /etc/init/mysql.conf to, replacing start on (net-device-up and local-filesystems) with start on runlevel [235] and it now starts at boot. It seems as though the links in /etc/rc2.d/ are meaningless. But it works, and I'm sure I can figure out the rest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While you can technically place the correct files by hand, the prefered method would be [update-rc.d](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-manage-services-with-update-rc.d)

Answer (score 0):

If your SysV scripts are faulty somehow, you could delete them manually and use *chkconfig* to set them for you.